# FB login button is not styled right

Tags: 7, social-network, users

I have a FB login button in the User login block. The login button has been working perfectly for months, but last night it broke. The functionaly still works (you can login), but the button shows tags to users:

```
<fb:intl>Login with Facebook account</fb:intl>
```

I upgraded Drupal core yesterday, but it should not have done anything to this. Today I tested it with old core version and the problem was still there. I have cleared all the caches, but no luck whatsoever.

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of how it looks like now? I have the same problem where my "like" button now have a blue background that as twice as big as the button itself.

Comment: Button looks like this: http://www.crossbordertravel.eu

Comment: It seems that there was a bug in the FB end, because everything is working now.